# Why does this program for creating 10 random coordinates that don't repeat not work?

Tags: python-3.x

I am creating a minesweeper program for school. Part of this is randomly assigning coordinates for 10 bombs. These will be placed in a 9x9 square. I don't want the bomb coordinates to repeat. Then I remove the coordinates of the bomb from the list buttonNames. I added print statements to try to figure out why this code didn't work.

This is my code:

```
    for i in range(11):
        Bombx = randrange(1,10)
        Bomby = randrange(1,10)
        newBomb = (Bombx,Bomby)
        self.BombList.append(newBomb)
        sumValues = []
        for (x,y) in self.BombList:
            value = x+y
            print(x,y)
            sumValues.append(value)
            for value in sumValues:
                count = sumValues.count(value)
                while count != 1:
                    Bombx = randrange(1,10)
                    Bomby = randrange(1,10)
                    newBomb = (Bombx,Bomby)
                    oldBomb = (x, y)
                    print(oldBomb)
                    self.BombList.remove(oldBomb)
                    self.BombList.append(newBomb)
                    count = 1
        self.buttonNames.remove(newBomb)
```

And it outputs this:

```
3 4
3 4
6 8
3 4
6 8
4 4
3 4
6 8
4 4
5 4
3 4
6 8
4 4
5 4
9 2
3 4
6 8
4 4
5 4
9 2
4 2
3 4
6 8
4 4
5 4
9 2
4 2
6 1
(6, 1)
(6, 1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/gould942/Documents/Intro Comp Sci/Minesweeper.py", line 222, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/gould942/Documents/Intro Comp Sci/Minesweeper.py", line 219, in main
    gameBoard = Sweeper(win)
  File "/Users/gould942/Documents/Intro Comp Sci/Minesweeper.py", line 98, in __init__
    self.BombList.remove(oldBomb)
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd ordinarily prefer to try to help you work out why your code is doing what it's doing, but to be honest I'm having a hard time trying to follow the logic. Instead I'll say that since there are only 9x9=81 options to choose from, the simple solution is to generate a sequence of all possible options and use [`random.sample()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/random.html#random.sample):

```
self.BombList = []
for x in range(1, 10):
    for y in range(1, 10):
        self.BombList.append((x, y))
self.BombList = random.sample(self.BombList, 9)
```

If you're familiar with list comprehensions, the whole thing can be done in one line:

```
self.BombList = random.sample([(x, y) for x in range(1, 10) for y in range(1, 10)], 9)
```

Comment: Thank you! I had some problems with sample giving an error message but I figured it out. I didn't realize sample existed, very helpful, thank you.